# RGB values as tuple in python

Tags: python

I am new to programming, I have a problem with an exercise.
I have a list of rgb values ​​that reproduce an image. I need an output a string with the following values:
X, Y, W, H, R, G, B
where X and Y are the coordinates, W and H are the width and height of the rectangle,
R G B are the colors.

For example:

```
image=[[(255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)],
[(255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)],
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)],
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)],
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0)],
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0)]]
```

and i need this output:

```
0,0,2,2,255,0,0
4,4,2,2,0,255,0
```

I'm trying with the coordinates but I'm stuck.

```
xy=[]
for row in image:
    for x in row:
        if x != (0,0,0):
            xy.append(row.index(x))
```

output:

```
xy=[0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `list.index` will always return first find - that's why whole upper left thing became 0s and lower right became 4s. Use `enumerate` to get both index and value during iteration. And store both coords and colour, maybe? Also notice your code doesn't detect rectangles, only non-black pixels.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot,
i am studying how enumerate works..thanks again

Comment: it's basically `for index, elem in enumerate(iterable)` instead of `for elem in iterable` (and then worrying about finding index) or `for index in range(len(iterable))` (or rather: sequence in this case, because it needs to have len and later be indexable with iterable[index] to get the element)

Comment: Can you clarify the image structure? The structure is `list(list(a,b,c)))` yet the desired output is 7 numerical values: X, Y, W, H, R, G, B. I would expect a tuple(X, Y, W, H, R, G, B) or perhaps structure((X,Y),(W,H),(R,G,B))

Comment: yes it is a tuple(X,Y,W,H,R,G,B).

Comment: I'm trying with enumerate, but it gives me all the index, I only need the x and the y where the rectangle begins..any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use 2D images? Using this representation you may lose spatial information (the vertical one).

Plus, you did not explain how you want to detect your rectangles, can they have any color? Then it would be harder, and I would suggest to use images (numpy, pillow, opencv or similar)

If still you want to do this way, we can assume rectangles have 3 colors (R, G or B)

```
# define colors
R = (255, 0, 0)
G = (0, 255, 0)
B = (0, 0, 255)

# detect them
rs = []
gs = []
bs = []
# loop for each row
for j, row in enumerate(image):
    # and for each value
    for k, val in enumerate(row):
        if val == R:
            rs.append((j,k))
        if val == G:
            gs.append((j,k))
        if val == B:
            bs.append((j,k))
print(rs, gs, bs)

# now you can extract the values
if len(rs) > 0:
    # the coordinates are the first value
    R_x, R_y = rs[0]
    # width is last minus first (+1)
    R_w = (rs[-1][0] - rs[0][0]) + 1
    # height the same
    R_h = (rs[-1][1] - rs[0][1]) + 1
    print(R_x, R_y, R_w, R_h, R)

if len(gs) > 0:
    G_x, G_y = gs[0]
    G_w = (gs[-1][0] - gs[0][0]) + 1
    G_h = (gs[-1][1] - gs[0][1]) + 1
print(G_x, G_y, G_w, G_h, G)
```

The output is `0 0 2 2 (255, 0, 0)` you may have to adjust it in a tuple, but this should be easy.

You can do this for rs, gs and bs (even though there are no blue rectangles), the output for gs is `4 4 2 2 (255, 0, 0)` which is the one that you want.

Was this your problem?

Note: as said, if the rectangles can be of any color, this will not work, maybe follow some [tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html)?

Comment: the rectangles can be of any color but thanks,you were helpful. i will see tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Example with and without enumerate.

```
# Some scratch code
image = [
    [(255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)],
    [(255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)],
    [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)],
    [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)],
    [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0)],
    [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0)]]
image_width = len(image[0])
image_height = len(image)
print(f'{image_height=} {image_width=}')

print(' xy without enumerate'.center(40, '*'))
xy = ''
for row in range(image_height):
    for column in range(image_width):
        result = (f'{column},{row},{image_width},{image_height},'
                  f'{image[row][column][0]},'
                  f'{image[row][column][0]},'
                  f'{image[row][column][0]}')
        xy = xy + result + '\n'
print(xy)

print(' xy with enumerate'.center(40, '*'))
xy = ''
""
for row, _ in enumerate(image):
    for column, _ in enumerate(image[0]):
        result = (f'{column},{row},{image_width},{image_height},'
                  f'{image[row][column][0]},'
                  f'{image[row][column][0]},'
                  f'{image[row][column][0]}')
        xy = xy + result + '\n'
print(xy)
```